# How can I get the created dates for all files in subdirectories

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a list of file path within a sub-directory. How can I find the created date for each of the file paths? I used the code below to get all the files within each sub-directory using Python:

```
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

find(pattern, Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these functions:

`os.path.getmtime(file_path)` or `os.path.getctime(file_path)`

Comment: More discussion on details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: @OnlyDryClean Codzy: I've put the filenames into a dataframe would I just refer to column name with the file_path?

Comment: @T17 No, you can't :) You can use map function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html or apply  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html